# Ruby Object and Module

Tags: ruby, object, module

I'm confused about these two class when I was reading Module document.
First of all, I saw there is a way to set the named constant to the given object.

`Object.const_set("FOO", 40)`

But I check ruby doc, there is no `const_set` in [Object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html) method, then I found out it was defined in [Module](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-const_set).

I thought `Object` is the default root of all Ruby objects. Why it can use module method? I am confused about the relationship between those.

Comment: Here's a hint: if you call `'Hello'.upcase`, where would you look for the `upcase` method … in the string `'Hello'` or in its class (`String`) and its superclasses? Now, if you call `Object.const_set`, where would you look for the `const_set` method … in the class `Object` or in its class (`Class`) and its superclasses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown below `:const_set` is an instance method stored in `Module`:

```
Module.instance_methods(false).include? :const_set #=> true
```

Also note that `Object` is an instance of `Class`:

```
Object.instance_of? Class #=> true
```

And `Class` is a subclass of `Module`:

```
Class.superclass #=> Module
```

All of this means that instance methods defined within `Module` are available to `Class` objects via inheritance. So any instance of `Class` (such as `Object`) has at its disposal all the instance methods (including `:const_set`) stored in `Module`.

Comment: Thanks, it's clear. Ruby is a really astonishing language to me.

Answer (score 1):

In ruby, basically every class is an instance of the `Class` class and every class is a subclass of `Object`. And both `Object` and `Class` are classes. If you do

```
Object.is_a?class 
Class.is_a?class
```

In both cases, you will get a `true` value. `Class` has `Module` as one of the ancestor, therefore, you can use

```
Object.const_set("FOO", 40)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also `#ancestors` to give you some more context on the object model.

```
> Module.ancestors
=> [Module, Object, PP::ObjectMixin, Kernel, BasicObject]
```